# Use Regular Expressions to Add Text to Beginning or End of Cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, search, regex, regexplace

I have a bunch of words in a sheet in one column, e.g.:

```
Study Guide 101 
Meditation for Beginners Cheatsheet 
Lose Weight Fast
```

What I want to do is **add a word to the end** of these in the cell using `Find & Replace` (not a formula), through regular expressions, **without using a formula or anything in another cell**.
The word to add would be `- EBOOK`

The same way can we can text to the front of the strings in cells, in this case `DD-EB-` (just an example).

I'm not sure whether this is entirely possible, but I got the idea from this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVzXpLJRcQk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to Add Text to Beginning or End of Cells without a formula

Please follow these steps

- **Step 1**
  Go to the top menu --> `Edit` --> `Find and replace`
- **Step 2**
  From `Search` choose `Specific range` and clicking on the little icon pick your range.
- **Step 3**
  **Check** the `Search using regular expressions` and **un-check** `Match case`
- **Step 4**

  - To **add text in the end**, on the `Find` field **use `$`**
  - To **add text in the beginning**, on the `Find` field **use `^`**
- **Step 5**
  On `Replace with` fill in `DD-EB-`  or  `- EBOOK`
- **Step 6**
  Press on `Find` and then on `Replace` (to replace one by one) or `Replace all` for one go.
- **Step 7**
  Click  `Done`
- **Step 8**
  Enjoy your newly created text :)

[image]

Comment: YOU ARE PURE GENIUS!!! I've been trying various combos since watching that video and all that time, this could be done with just 2 characters! This will save me a lot of trouble! You have no idea how grateful I am! :) :) :D :D I would thumbs up your answers a thousand times if I could! :D

Comment: *"I would thumbs up your answers a thousand times if I could"*. Thank you Genny :)